# How would I customize an SDK's UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

So, I already understand & can create my own custom `UIAlertController` (fonts, background color, text color, tint color, etc). So that is not the issue here.

The problem I'm running into is:

When I'm using an SDK file (ex. Facebook's SDK), I'm not able to find where inside of the SDK's Objective-C Headers, that the default `UIAlertController` is begin initiated (and presented). If I could, I'd like to replace the default with my own custom alert.

As of right now, I've already create my custom class with a static function that returns my custom `UIAlertController` for my VC to present. I've also already tested the implementation & it's works fine.

What I tried first was to manually search through Facebook's SDK Objective-C headers to find where the default `UIAlertController` is being initiated & then presented, but obviously with little luck...

Next thing I tried was using Xcode's Find Navigator to search for, "AlertController". Alas, nothing found inside the SDK's header files (maybe I should change the search scope?).

Last thing I tried was simply searching Google, but all I could find there was tutorials on how to create a custom `UIAlertController` (which I already know how to do).

Although in my current situation, I am using Facebook's SDK. Best answer would be one that's more general rather than specific (if possible). That way if I'm using a different/new SDK in the future, I can still apply your method. Thanks.

Comment: UIAlertController is a UIKit class, that has nothing to do with Facebook whatsoever. Look at the UIKit documentation.

Comment: To add to this, `UIAlertController` is not meant to be customized. If you want to change things like fonts/background color/etc. you should make a custom `ViewController` that mimics `UIAlertController`'s behavior and use that as your alert.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend editing and forking FB's SDK, that would be a nightmare to maintain.

Instead you should look into objc method Swizzling, which allows you to dynamically replace the body of existing functions with your own implementation. I believe you could use this to change the behavior of all UIAlertControllers (not without risk).

https://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/